# Fill column cells with values based on a series of conditions

Tags: excel, function, excel-formula, array-formulas

I am struggling with writing a function to fill the cells in a column depending on the given values of other columns.

So based on the sample columns below, I would like to create a function that returns a specific value depending on the values of the Type, Kind, and Status columns.

```
Eg if type = 'AE', Kind = 'NOM' and Status = '', then cost = 20

   if type = 'AE', Kind = 'ANA' and Status = '', then cost = 15

   if type = 'AE', Kind = 'ANA' and Status = 'PROS', then cost = 17
```

Likewise for other values of the type column.

I am looking to shorten the function as much as possible, meaning having not to write a long string of IF(AND(...,...) statements.

Based on the above example I can see that there is a common condition between the smaller if statements, namely the if type = 'AE'.

I have tried using IFS function.

In the end, I opted for the SWITCH function which ensured better readability.

This function would supposedly check if the relevant cell in the type column contains the 'AE' value, and if yes, then if the value in cell B1 is 'ΝΟΜ', return the value of 20 or if the value in B1 is 'AN', return the value 15.

```
=SWITCH(A1,'AE', SWITCH (B1, 'NOM',20'ΑΝ',15))
```

However, I can not get my created function to work properly.

Comment: If your return value is numeric (e.g. 20, 15, 17), then use a lookup table and SUMIFS.

Comment: Several solutions to this on here already. Have a look.